# Send INSERT and F12 in expect script

Tags: bash, unix, expect

I know that in order to send return in an expect script I do something like this:

```
send -- "\r"
```

What is the send command for the <kbd>INSERT</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> keys? I've looked online and cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: FYI - One way how you can find the exact key codes for certain keys is eg. via `xev` (when running Xorg, installable via eg. `apt-get install xev`) or `showkey` if you are on a `PTY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say the initially accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50583731/2) is not correct because

1. The real char sequence is not the same for different terminal types;
2. `send -- "[2~"` is wrong because

   1. `[` in Tcl has special meaning (command substitution) so it should be backslash-escaped;
   2. The <kbd>ESC</kbd> char (`\E` as in `infocmp`'s output) is missing;

The correct way:

```
set kf12 [exec tput kf12]
set kins [exec tput kich1]
... ...
send $kf12
```

If you need to manually specify the TERM type, use [`tput -T`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tput.1.html):

> - -T*type*
>
>   indicates the *type* of terminal.  Normally this option is  unnecessary,  because the default is taken from the environment variable `TERM`.  If `-T` is specified, then the shell  variables  `LINES` and `COLUMNS` will also be ignored.

For the magic strings `kf12` and `kich1`, search in the [terminfo manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html) page.

Answer (score 2):

Using `infocmp xterm` as source:

```
$ infocmp xterm |grep -oP "f12=\S+|kich1=\S+"
f12=\E[24~,
kich1=\E[2~,
```

- INSERT: `send -- "[2~"` or `send -- {[2~}`
- F12:    `send -- "[24~"` or `send -- {[24~}`

Comment: Thanks, I tried the above-mentioned command and get a `missing close-bracket` error message. How do I fix it?

Comment: Hi @methuselah see the alternative in the edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Identify the characters that your terminal sends when you press <kbd>INSERT</kbd> followed by <kbd>F12</kbd> by running `od -c`:

```
$ od -c
^[[2z^[[193z       <-- Press keys here, then ENTER and Ctrl-D
0000000 033   [   2   z 033   [   1   9   3   z  \n
0000013
```

This means you should `send -- "\E\[2z\E\[193z"`. Note that this is terminal specific. The sequence above is sent by my `TERM=xterm-256color`.