# How to trigger keboard input using bash script

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel

I want to control keyboard input using bash script.

I found out that my keyboard is connected to /dev/input/event5.
And, I was able to get the hex value of the "F12" button I want to input by using the hexdump command.

```
root@intel-corei7-64:/dev/input# hexdump /dev/input/event5
0000000 cb67 6270 0000 0000 1e09 0001 0000 0000
0000010 0004 0004 0045 0007 cb67 6270 0000 0000
0000020 1e09 0001 0000 0000 0001 0058 0001 0000
0000030 cb67 6270 0000 0000 1e09 0001 0000 0000
0000040 0000 0000 0000 0000 cb67 6270 0000 0000
0000050 1812 0002 0000 0000 0004 0004 0045 0007
0000060 cb67 6270 0000 0000 1812 0002 0000 0000
0000070 0001 0058 0000 0000 cb67 6270 0000 0000
0000080 1812 0002 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

I want to trigger a keyboard signal using this hex value.
How can i do this? I want to make it into a shell script that behaves like pressing F12.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You don't want to press F12, you want to do whatever happens when F12 is pressed. If you explain what that behaviour is, maybe we can help cut out the middle man.

Answer (score 1):

**Using X Server `xdotool` utility**

`xdotool` command can be used inside the shell script to trigger any keyboard signals.

To simulate a keypress, use:

```
xdotool key <key>
```

For example, to simulate pressing F12:

```
xdotool key F12
```

You can install the same if you are using debian, Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Or, if you are using Fedora then install using the following commands.

```
sudo yum install xdotool
```

This should be useful for simulating the keyboard input.
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html

**Using tput**

Insert following into shell script.

```
set kf12 [exec tput kf12]
send $kf12
```

Please check following [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tput.1.html) for tput.

For various characters, please see [terminfo manpage.](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html)

References Links:

1. https://www.xmodulo.com/simulate-key-press-mouse-movement-linux.html
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267704/command-to-simulate-keyboard-input
3. [Send INSERT and F12 in expect script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583381/send-insert-and-f12-in-expect-script)

Comment: As the same suggests, `xdotool` is an X utility, so this answer assumes that one is running X :)

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for pointing out that limitation. I have edited the answer to use it with terminals as well.

Comment: All that stuff only works on systems where it is allowed. On my box sending things to different consoles results in an security exception which is good :-)

Comment: I didn't get that. Are you able to use the xdotool? Do you mean that xdotool is not sending to the specific consoles? Maybe you can check the --window windowid option.